# get date and save it as a file name python

Tags: python, date, save

I have some graph that I do in python.

In the end  I save the plot to a png file.
Here is the code:

```
plt.scatter(LuxCoordinates, finalPix, linewidths=1)
plt.sca
plt.grid(axis)
plt.xlabel('Ambient', color='r');
plt.ylabel('Depth Grows', color='r'); # grayscale color
plt.title(PngName, color='b');
savefig(PngName+'.png'); #PngName is the name of the file that the user gives in argv
```

This work good and it save me a file, name PngName.png (Where PngName is what the user decided)

Now I want to add to that name the current date.
I had try to do this:

```
date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
plt.scatter(LuxCoordinates, finalPix, linewidths=1)
plt.sca
plt.grid(axis)
plt.xlabel('Ambient', color='r');
plt.ylabel('Depth Grows', color='r'); # grayscale color
plt.title(PngName, color='b');
savefig(PngName+'_'+date+'.png')
```

But it's not working, I get this error message:

> filename_or_obj = open(filename_or_obj, 'wb')
>   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '05/12/2013.png'

You can see that the date variable get the date. (also when I'm printing it to screen I see the date)

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your filename `05/12/2013.png` contains slashes (`/`) and these are likely pathname separator characters on your OS.  In other words, the filename you are trying to write to is `2013.png` in the directory `12`, under the directory `05`.  If that's not what you want, then consider changing your filename format to something like `time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`, or anything else without slashes.

Comment: Thank you! I marked the other answer because he wrote the same thing first, but in a comment, and change it now to answer

Comment: @shlomi That's nice of you, but his string format suggestion is better than my replace-option :p

Comment: That's nice of you, @shlomi! :)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly adding to the answer given by Darren Stone:

```
# Time stamp with date and time
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")

# save plot
savefig("Figure "+ time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S") + ".png")
```